# Database design for sports meeting(in MySQL)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to design a database for a sports meeting.

I think I've got something good but I'm not quite sure.

The situation is as follows.

There is the meeting, several sportsclubs will each send a number of athletes: 1 or more.
The athletes can enter in more then one event.
There are several events: Marathon, pole-juming, spear throwing, ...

Each event has a first round, Quarter final, Half final and Final.
Each individual event has 1 official who takes down the data, be it time, height or distance.

So basically, there's an N:M relationship here with the athletes and events.
1 Athlete can enter many events and there are many events, which can be entered by more then one athlete.

I thought there was going to be the same thing with the clubs and the athletes, but I just put a field 'club_id' in the Athletes table to refer to which club the come from.

What I have is this:

```
Table Clubs:
club_id int primary key auto_increment not null,
club_name varchar(50) not null

Table Athletes:
athlete_id int primary key auto_increment not null,
athlete_name varchar(40) not null,
athlete_club int not null,
index (athlete_club),
foreign key (athlete_club) references Clubs(club_id)

Table Events:
event_id int primary key auto_increment not null, (if there's a new round, it's a new event too)
event_name varchar(40) not null,
official_id int not null,
round enum('FIRST','QUARTER','HALF','FINAL')

Table Participations:
athlete_id int not null,
event_id int not null,
primary key (athlete_id,event_id),
index (athlete_id),
index (event_id),
foreign key (athlete_id) references Athletes(athlete_id),
foreign key (event_id) references Events(event_id)
```

And I think that's basically it.
What's missing is a way to connect the series to the results.
So I'm thinking there should be another N:M relation, since an athlete can go on to the final or drop somewhere in between, but every round they did, their scores need to be noted down.

So for instance, I need to be able to make a query which basically gives me 'the names of all athletes whos times were faster then 5 minutes for a certain event in a certain round'

Or a list of the rounds one athlete did in one event, or a list of all athletes who got to a certain round...

I'm not quite sure how to add this.

Comment: Consider using something like mysql workbench (free) to design your tables visually, that will often help to visualize relationships and where data belongs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a result field to the participation table

Comment: indeed, now that you mention it. I was wondering how to get the different results for different kinds of events in there, but there's no need, since the event_id is linked to the event_name and thusly, I'll just make the result field a varchar or a TEXT field holding '15 m' or '32 seconds'

Answer (score 1):

What your asking is more of an application question then a DB question. Your DB design looks fine for what you need. What you need to do now is write your application to query the database. A few SELECTS and JOINS and you should have no problems!